# Add Images to QnA Maker

Tags: azure, azure-qna-maker

How to Add Images to QnA Maker? 
I would like to put picture in qna maker (knowledge base).
Any help please.

```
[Michael Szul's Twitter]          (https://img.thedailybeast.com/image/upload/c_crop,d_placeholder_euli9k,h_1440,w_2560,x_0,y_0/dpr_1.5/c_limit,w_1044/fl_lossy,q_auto/v1505327080/170911-cox-bots-politics-tease_hflhdh)
```

Comment: you would like to add the image itself in the KB or its Url ?

Answer (score 13):

As per the QnAMaker documentation:

> The knowledge base supports Markdown. However, the auto-extraction from URLs has limited HTML-to-Markdown conversion capability. If you want to use full-fledged Markdown, you can modify your content directly in the table, or upload a knowledge base with the rich content. Multimedia, such as images and videos, is not supported at this time."

- Using Markdowns : you can add images to a QnAMaker answer by adding the URl via markdowns.

```
![Image](https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/03/11/20/42/mammals-3218028__340.jpg)
```

This will result in 
[image]

What you have pasted above will render as a link.
If you want to add links via markdown, then the format is

```
 [bing](http://bing.com)
```

which will result in

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Glad that it helped. Can you accept the answer so that it helps others?Thanks

Comment: How can we add embedded image? Ex we have one index based document as a source to QnA maker. It contains some images into it. We can not host these images to make it as markdown/url based rendering. In this case how can we load embedded images from document?

Comment: It is not possible to add embedded images from an index based doc. As per the QnA Maker documentation, "QnA Maker doesn't process the image in any way. It is the client application's role to render the image". Refer to the data sources for QnA Maker content [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/concepts/data-sources-supported) for detailed explanation.